# Non-Markovian Basketball Player Puzzle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following puzzle I recently heard:

> Suppose a basketball player is shooting ten free throws. He makes the first, and misses the second. For every subsequent shot, his probability of making that shot is the percentage of shots already made (i.e., probability of making the third is $1/2$). What is the probability that out of $10$ shots, he makes exactly $5$ of them?

I have an idea of how to solve the problem, but I can't quite finish it. For the player to make 5 shots, at any point he must have exactly one shot made, two shots made... 4 shots made in no particular order. And at each stage he must have already taken a total of 2 shots, 3 shots... 9 shots.

Therefore I have a fraction that looks something like this:
$$
\frac{{\displaystyle\binom{8}{4}} \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9}
$$
where $4!$ is the total number of shots already made, $\binom{8}{4}$ is the number of ways of arranging those makes, and $9!$ is the total number of shots taken.

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I don't feel like I've taken into account the fact that the five misses could be between any of the makes in any order.

Comment: Do you mean at least $5$ or exactly $5$?  Either way, I'd sample the process first to get a numerical sense of the probabilities.

Comment: And to compute it, I'd use Markov methods.  States would be pairs $(h,m)$ where $h$ is the prior number of hits, and $m$ the prior number of misses.  We start at $(1,1)$ of course and $(h,m)$ can go to $(h+1,m)$ and $(h, m+1)$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the comment. I'll admit, my familiarity with Markov chains is pretty elementary. What kind of transition matrix would you use for a problem like this? And how exactly would you calculate the probability of the state eventually reaching (5,5)?

Comment: Just go step by step.  You can do it by hand, though it is a bit tedious.  It helps to note that the probability of reaching state $(i,j)$ is the same as the probability of reaching state $(j,i)$ so you only have to compute about half.  For instance, given that you start at $(1,1)$ you have a $\frac 12$ chance of going either to $(1,2)$ or to $(2,1)$.  So now build on that to get the next stage.

Comment: Should say:  perhaps there is a symmetry argument that lets you get the probability of reaching $(i,i)$ quickly. When you do the probability of getting to $(2,2)$, say, that might clarify things.

Comment: Oh, yes. Once you have done the next stage or two, the pattern becomes clear.  And not just for the diagonal.  You can quickly get all the probabilities.

Comment: This is an example of [Pólya urn model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model). A crucial observation is that the probability of each list of successes/fails to occur is only determined by the number of successes and fails in the list (experiment this with some concrete cases!), from which the desired probability can be easily computed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use dynamic programming like approach here.

Let $P(k,n)$ denote the probability that the player makes exactly k shots in n throws.

If the player made exactly $k$ shots in $n$ throws, she either had $k-1$ or $k$ shots in $n-1$ throws.

Case 1: Player made $k$ shots in $n-1$ throws. So her success probability is $k/n$. Conditioned on this,

$P(k,n) = (1-k/n)P(k,n-1) + (k/n)P(k+1,n)$

Case 2: Player made $k-1$ shots in $n-1$ throws. So her success rate is (k-1)/(n-1). Conditioned on this,

$P(k,n) = (k-1)/(n-1)P(k-1,n-1) + (1-(k-1)/(n-1))P(k-1,n)$

Combining the above, $P(k,n) = (1-k/n)P(k,n-1) + (k/n)P(k+1,n) + (k-1)/(n-1)P(k-1,n-1) + (1-(k-1)/(n-1))P(k-1,n)$.

You also have the boundary conditions:
$P(0,1) = 0, P(1,1) = 1, P(0,2) = 0, P(1,2)=1, P(2,2)=0$

It's unlikely there is a closed form here, but you should be able to evaluate $P(5,10)$ numerically.

The transition probabilities are a function of the state, so that's interesting.